# Python: Download multiple .gz files from single URL

Tags: python, urllib

I am having trouble downloading multiple network files from an online directory. I am using a virtual Linux environment (Lubuntu) over VMware.
My aim is to access a subfolder and download all the .gz files it contains into a new local directory that is different from the home directory. I tried multiple solutions and this is the closest I got.

```
import os
from urllib2 import urlopen, URLError, HTTPError
def dlfile(url):
    # Open the url
    try:
        f = urlopen(url)
        print "downloading " + url

        # Open our local file for writing
        with open(os.path.basename(url), "wb") as local_file:
            local_file.write(f.read())

    #handle errors
    except HTTPError, e:
        print "HTTP Error:", e.code, url
    except URLError, e:
        print "URL Error:", e.reason, url


def main():
    # Iterate over image ranges
    for index in range(100, 250,5):
        url = ("http://data.ris.ripe.net/rrc00/2016.01/updates20160128.0%d.gz"
                %(index))
        dlfile(url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The online directory needs no authentication, a link can be found [here](http://data.ris.ripe.net/rrc00/2016.01/).

I tried string manipulation and using a loop over the filenames, but it gave me the following error:

```
HTTP Error: 404 http://data.ris.ripe.net/rrc00/2016.01/updates20160128.0245.gz
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a '.' after 'updates' from the url http://data.ris.ripe.net/rrc00/2016.01/updates.20160128.0345.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the url

Good url: `http://data.ris.ripe.net/rrc00/2016.01/updates.20160128.0245.gz`

Bad url (your code): `http://data.ris.ripe.net/rrc00/2016.01/updates20160128.0245.gz`

A dot between updates and 2016 is missing